# Conflict when binding two different instances of same viewModal to two distincts div with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

As we can see in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rubenslopes/dgnLwjs0/4/) when I try to select an item in List 2 that also exist in List 1 this item is selected in List 1 instead been selected in List 2.

```
var viewModel = function (_index, _params) {
    var self = this;

$('#volatile-select-' + _index + ' input[type=text]').focus(function () {
    $('#volatile-select-' + _index + ' .volatile-select-body').show();
});

self.filter = ko.observable('');
self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray();
self.callbackList = _params.value;
self.items = _params.options;

self.filteredItems = ko.computed(function () {
    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');

    if (!filter) return self.items;
    else return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items, function (o) {
        var match = false;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(o.Sectors, function (s) {
            var fullName = (o.Name + s.Name).replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
            if (fullName.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                match = true;
                return;
            }
        });
        return match;
    });
}).extend({
    throttle: 500
});
self.filteredSectors = function (i) {
    var filter = self.filter().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '');

    if (!filter) return i.Sectors;
    else return ko.utils.arrayFilter(i.Sectors, function (s) {
        var fullName = (i.Name + s.Name).replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase();
        return (fullName.indexOf(filter) > -1);
    });
};

self.focus = function () {
    $('#volatile-select-' + _index + ' input[type=text]').focus();
};
self.close = function () {
    self.filter('');
    $('#volatile-select-' + _index + ' .volatile-select-body').hide();
};
self.clear = function () {
    self.close();
    self.selectedItems.removeAll();
};

self.isUpdatingSelectedItems = false;
self.selectedItems.subscribe(function (changes) {
    if (self.isUpdatingSelectedItems) return;

    self.isUpdatingSelectedItems = true;
    changes.forEach(function (change) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.items, function (item) {
            if (change.status === 'added' && item.GroupId == change.value) ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.Sectors, function (s) {
                if (self.selectedItems.indexOf(s.GroupId) == -1) self.selectedItems.push(s.GroupId);
            });
            if (change.status === 'deleted' && item.GroupId == change.value) ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.Sectors, function (s) {
                if (self.selectedItems.indexOf(s.GroupId) > -1) self.selectedItems.remove(s.GroupId);
            });
        });
    });
    self.callbackList(ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.selectedItems(), function (si) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.items, function (o) {
            return o.GroupId == si;
        }) === null;
    }));
    self.isUpdatingSelectedItems = false;
}, null, 'arrayChange');
```

};

Any questions about the details in the viewModel just ask me.

Comment: The fiddle is a little hard to use, the input fields aren't showing everything they should. Could you clean it up?

Comment: @AnotherDev got the css on fliddle fixed and the link to example updated http://jsfiddle.net/rubenslopes/dgnLwjs0/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/dgnLwjs0/5/

Your groupId ends up being the id for the input, so you end up with multiple `<input id='1'..`, which is not valid. Use different groupIds between the two lists. i.e.

```
var params = {
'options': [{
    'GroupId': '1',
        'GroupType': '2',
        'Name': 'Local 1',
        'Sectors': [{
        'GroupId': '2',
            'Name': 'Setor 1'
    }, {
        'GroupId': '3',
            'Name': 'Setor 2'
    }]
```

and

```
params = {
'options': [{
    'GroupId': '111',
        'GroupType': '2',
        'Name': 'Local 1',
        'Sectors': [{
        'GroupId': '222',
            'Name': 'Setor 1'
    }, {
        'GroupId': '333',
            'Name': 'Setor 2'
```